# Search Script with Pagination defect in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

I am trying to make PHP search script with pagination option it's working fine until we are on the 1st page like If I typed in search 'car', but when go to next page search query rest to non and show all results available in the database

Here is my PHP Script

```
 $_SESSION['word'] = $_POST['term'];

 $term = $_SESSION['word'];

    $term = explode(" ",$term);
    if (count($term) > 0) {
       $Where = '';
       foreach($term as $Item) {
          $Where .= "Title like '%$Item%' OR ";
       }
       $Where = substr($Where,0,-4);
     $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM data where $Where"; 
     $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


     $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);


     // Here we have the total row count
      $rows = $row[0];
     // This is the number of results we want displayed per page 
     $page_rows = 15;
     // This tells us the page number of our last page 
     $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
     // This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1 
     if($last < 1){ $last = 1; }
     // Establish the $pagenum variable 
     $pagenum = 1;
     // Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1 
     if(isset($_GET['pn'])){ $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']); }
     // This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page 
     if ($pagenum < 1) { $pagenum = 1; } else if ($pagenum > $last) { $pagenum = $last; }
     // This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum 
     $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
     // This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying $limit 
     $sql = "SELECT *  FROM data where $Where ORDER BY RAND() $limit"; 

     $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if (!$query) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        exit();
    }
     // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages 
     $textline1 = "<div id='toptext'>Total Videos Found: (<b>$rows</b>)</div>"; $textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
     // Establish the $paginationCtrls variable 
     $paginationCtrls = '';
     // If there is more than 1 page worth of results if($last != 1){ /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */ 
     if ($pagenum > 1) { $previous = $pagenum - 1; $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
     // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number 
     for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){ if($i > 0){ $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; '; } } }
     // Render the target page number, but without it being a link 
     $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
     // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number 
     for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){ $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; '; if($i >= $pagenum+4){ break; } }
     // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next" 
     if ($pagenum != $last) {{ $next = $pagenum + 1; $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> '; } } $list = ''; 
     $width = "200";
      $hight = "150";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     { 
        $post_id = $row['ID'];
        $title = $row['Link'];
        $ti = $row['Title'];
        $pic = $row['img'];



        $list .= '<div style="text-align:center" id="body"><div id="tablealign"><a href="Video.php?ID='.$post_id.'"><img  id="image" src='.$pic.' width='.$width.' height='. $hight.'></a></div><div id="text"><a href="Video.php?ID='.$post_id.'">'.wordwrap($ti, 30, "<br />\n").'</a></div></div>'; 

     }}
     // Close your database connection 
     mysqli_close($con); ?> 

     <!DOCTYPE html> <html> 
     <?php echo $textline1; ?> <p><?php echo $textline2; ?><center><div id="pagelayout" >
     <div id="pagenum"> <?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></body></html></div></div></center></p>  <p><?php echo $list; ?></p>
```

Here is the html code

```
 <form action="process.php" class="searchform" method="post" id="search-form">

      <input type="text" class="searchfield" placeholder="Search..." name="term" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="searchbutton" value="GO" >
    </form>
```

**Check out the demo:**
http://vidupdatez.com/Demo/Search.php
Search for Car and then click on page 2 you will see what's the problem

Comment: Of course this does not work, if your script relies on the search term being passed by POST, and then you call the next page via GET. Either make the pagination “links” use POST as well (means, actually use a form instead of links), or transfer the search term to the next page via GET, or put it into the session so that you have access to it on the following pages.

Comment: Or if they want to continue using a combination of GET/POST requests, they could use PHP's `$_REQUEST` variable to get an associative array of `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. ([see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php))

Comment: @CBroe do you mean change post to GET or store search term in session variable

Comment: Yes, I mean “or”, that’s why I _wrote_ “or”.

Comment: are you creating the page URL dynamically ?

Comment: @CBroe Added session but still no help check the code updated

Comment: Well if you are overwriting the session value with a non-existing POST value on every following page, there’s not much gained …

Comment: http://vidupdatez.com/ad.jpg